# IText 5 Pdf Table column width not working

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF file formatted for an Avery name label 5395, which has 8 labels on an 8 1/2 x 11 sheet. I set up a PdfPTable with measurements from the actual sheet, and write it out. The problem is the column widths and overall table width are wrong. Instead of columns 3.5" they are about 2.8". My code is below. What am I missing?

```
public class TryNameLabelPdf {
public static void main(String[] args) {
PdfPTable theTable;
Document theDoc;
    try {
        // Avery 5395 Name Badges
        theDoc = new Document();
        Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(612f,792f); // 8.5*72 = 612, 11*72= 792
        theDoc.setPageSize(pageSize);
        theDoc.setMargins(49.5f, 49.5f,41.06f, 41.06f);  // left, right, top, bottom
        theTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        float[] columnWidths = {252f, 252f}; // 3.5*72 = 252
        theTable.setWidths(columnWidths);        
        theTable.setTotalWidth(504f); // 2*252 = 504
        PdfWriter.getInstance(theDoc, new FileOutputStream("MyTestTable.pdf"));
        theDoc.open();
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1.1"));
        cell1.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1.2"));
        cell2.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2.1"));
        cell3.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2.2"));
        cell4.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3.1"));
        cell5.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3.2"));
        cell6.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4.1"));
        cell7.setFixedHeight(174);
        PdfPCell cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4.2"));
        cell8.setFixedHeight(174);
        theTable.addCell(cell1);
        theTable.addCell(cell2);
        theTable.addCell(cell3);
        theTable.addCell(cell4);
        theTable.addCell(cell5);
        theTable.addCell(cell6);
        theTable.addCell(cell7);
        theTable.addCell(cell8);
        theDoc.add(theTable);
        theDoc.close();
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TryNameLabelPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TryNameLabelPdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! Turns out the column width needs to be locked after setting:

```
            theTable.setLockedWidth(true); // Without this the table width won't stick!
```